# Is it possible to guarantee each different kernel stream cannot be interleaved?

Tags: cuda

If the kernel is launched with different streams,

can we guarantee that each stream does not interleave?

It seems that different kernel streams are interleaved together.

What I want to is that issued kernel stream has to wait until previous launched kernel stream finishes its job.

The reason why I want to is that different stream kernel must not pollute L2cache data used by current running kernel stream.

Is this possible?

Comment: launch an event at the end of the kernel you launch in stream A.  In stream B, do a `cudaStreamWaitEvent` on the event launched in stream A.  After that point in stream B,everything will wait for Stream A to get to the event.  Your question appears to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445282/synchronising-multiple-cuda-streams).

Comment: @Robert thank you. Let me dive into your link page

Comment: The usual (stream) method to prevent CUDA activities X and Y from overlapping is to launch those activities into the same stream.

Comment: @Robert I know that is the basic. But the problem is second kernel has to be launched after memcpy is done. This means that second kernel stream has to be different from first kernel stream since second kernel must not wait for the memcpy.

Comment: _"second kernel has to be launched after memcpy is done"_ vs _"second kernel must not wait for the memcpy"_ - that appears contradictory to me. Can you clarify?

Comment: @tera The former was that memcpy function (assume stream 2) right before launching second kernel (stream 2) copies data required in second kernel. The latter was that first kernel (stream 1) has to copy data from device to host (stream1) after its execution (in my case), and the second kernel (stream 2) doesn't have to wait memcpy function(stream 1) if stream is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events allow you to synchronize streams against each other without having to synchronize them against the calling CPU thread. You can use `cudaEventRecord(event1, stream1)` to record an event in stream1 and then use `cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream2, event1)` to make stream2 wait for that event before proceeding onward. If you then examine your application in nvprof you'll notice the synchronization between streams always occurring at that event.

I've seen people set up messy cudaStreamSynchronize() calls in an attempt to use the calling CPU thread to create synchronization between streams. Do not do this. Use events.